# How to convert full width characters to half width characters

Tags: sql, oracle

In my Oracle database I have the following table

```
 FULL_WIDTH_NUM
１３５－００６１
 ＫＤＤＩ（株）
１７０－００１２
１７０－００１２
１７０－００１２
１３５－００５２
１３５－００６１
１７０－００１２
２６１－００２３
```

I am running my query in TOAD. The field's character set is AL16UTF16. I want to convert this field into half width characters. 
When I try using to_single_byte on the field, I get ORA-29275:  partial multibyte character. Why am I getting this ORA-29275:  partial multibyte character? Is there another way I should be converting this field into half width characters?

Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to say that I am using Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Fullwidth characters aren't made up of just tacking on empty space bytes onto either side of a regular character - they're totally different characters, so you have to translate them.

Fortunately, you can just convert the fullwidth characters to their integer values and subtract 15711328 to get the ASCII equivalent. You can double-check this number on your system by doing `select ascii('１')-49 from dual;` (49 = ASCII '1'). *(I don't remember why Oracle Unicode decimal values are different than you'd expect - normally you'd subtract 65248, since the fullwidth block starts at U+FF01.)*

Anyway, assuming here that your table is named `my_table`:

```
select listagg(chr(fw_char2)) within group(order by lvl) 
from
  (select rid, lvl, 
      CASE WHEN ascii(fw_char) between 15711328 and 15712174 
           THEN ascii(fw_char)-15711328
           ELSE ascii(fw_char) 
      END as fw_char2
   from 
      (select my_table.rowid as rid, 
              substr(full_width_num, lvl, 1) as fw_char, 
              lvl
        from my_table
        join (select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 4000) 
            on lvl <= length(full_width_num)
      ) splitfield
   )
group by rid
;
```

The innermost query splits up each field into 1-char segments. The next one out (with fw_char2) subtracts 15711328 if the character is in the Unicode fullwidth block. The outermost query just converts them back into characters and pastes it all together.

If you have some other unique key besides rowid, that'd probably be cleaner.